# Android chat client that supports IRC and XMPP

Tags: android, chat, xmpp, irc

At work, we use XMPP, and for personal use, I use IRC.

Are there any Android clients that support both, similar to Pidgin on Windows?

Comment: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android&hl=en

Comment: The first supports neither, the second only XMPP.